# How should DC motor brush capacitors be sized?

Tags: capacitor, pwm, dc-motor

I have seen capacitors placed near the brush connectors on DC motors.

- What are these for?
- How should they be sized?
- Do they affect PWM behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are for EMC - noise suppression, interference with radio transmissions.

0.1uF disc ceramics are commonly used, in a triangle (delta) - one from each brush to GND (the can) and one between the two brushes.

Should have essentially no effect on PWM.

Comment: I've also seen small ceramics in the 100pF range. No idea on the effect difference, it's for for brush/commutator noise anyway

Answer (score 1):

Since pwm from an MCU or an 555 IC is not used directly to the motor (a transistor/fet is placed between) it should not affect the pwm behavior.

[image]
picture from [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/pulse-width-modulation.html)

Various explanations can be found online like [here](https://www.etechnog.com/2019/06/capacitor-with-dc-motor.html)

> The first and main reason is to reduce interference and noise. When
> the motor is in running condition, there is very frequently connect
> and disconnect happens between the brush and commutator. So the motor
> armature winding also connects and disconnect to the power supply
> frequency. This connection and disconnection are happening too fast.
> For this reason, the changes in motor current also happen too fast
> which creates magnetic interference and create disruption in nearby
> radio devices such as FM, AM receivers.
>
> So to reduce this interference, a capacitor is connected across the
> motor terminals. Capacitor reduces the spikes in the motor current and
> reduces the magnetic interference.

Normally, the larger the Capacitor the better. But a larger capacitor means it costs more, it has more ESR and adds to the size and weight of the motor.

Answer (score -2):

They are for EMI suppression. They largely affect PWM operation, since the capacitor behaves like a short circuit for high frequency, it will blow your MOSFETs. Either remove them or place two chokes in series (the correct solution), one on each wire.

Comment: 1 KHz PWM isn't quite enough for a capacitor short circuit...